# How to make a default configuration for any wlan interface

Tags: networking, wifi, configuration

I have a Ubuntu server (14.04) embedded machine and I would like to be able to change the WiFi dongle without having to create a new interface.

Indeed, when I plug a new wlan interface, it is seen as wlan(N+1).

I would see two 'solutions' but I don't know how do it:

- Make a default WPA settings that any wlan interface will use (preferred)
- Make sure any wlan interface I plug will be seen as wlan0 (while only one interface is plugged in at the same time)

Comment: One solution could be using UDEV rules to adapt numbering https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73595/wlan-number-assignment

Answer (score 1):

A sample script to connect through `wpa_supplicant` independently of the wifi interface name ( `wlan0` , ... `wlanN`)

```
#!/bin/bash
killall wpa_supplicant
i=$(iw dev | grep Interface | awk '{ print $2}')
wpa_supplicant -i $i -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient $i
```

The `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` configuration file should contain the following lines:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
ap_scan=1

network={
         ssid="your_ssid"
         psk="your_wifi_password"
        }
```